# EE in subfolder not working correctly

Tags: url, path, themes

I've got EE running in a subfolder on a dev environment, such as:

```
http://website.com/folder_name/
```

But somehow, the folder keeps being removed from the URL for certain things. E.g. the "Home" icon on the home button in EE errors, because the URL looks like this:

```
/themes/cp_themes/default/images/home_icon.png
```

Not:

```
/folder_name/themes/cp_themes/default/images/home_icon.png
```

How can I fix this? There is no .htaccess file at the moment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete this out of your .htaccess when accessing EE from a sub folder:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: You could also rewrite the base to include the sub folder than just removing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a configuration value for the location of your themes directory. By default, in EE you'd change those by going here in the EE control panel:

Admin > General Configuration > URL to your "themes" folder

Eventually, many developers start setting configuration options like that in their config.php file; in this case, `$config['theme_folder_path']`and  `$config['theme_folder_url']` would be the applicable items. Delving into auto-setting dev/staging/production settings in config.php is beyond the scope of this post, but, is something you'll probably want to look into, if you haven't already.

Comment: Yeah, I checked that and all is good. The theme folder is correct in there but it just seems to be removing the "folder_name" bit of the URL. It's like .htaccess is doing something, or the server itself.

Comment: Are you seeing the correct URL when you do a view source? Do you have another copy of EE installed in the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your .htaccess file needs to account for your subfolder when removing index.php for EE. Here's a code snippet you can use.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    # IF YOU HAVE WEBSITE IN A SUB FOLDER: comment out above line, uncomment below line, & replace 'SUBFOLDERNAME'
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /SUBFOLDERNAME/index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```